# Getting Parskip Inside a Table

Tags: tables, formatting, parskip

I am trying to add parskip to the tables in my document. In all my text I have parskip working correctly, but it does not seem to work inside the table cell. Could someone kindly explain how I can get that working?

The code is below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}, margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|>{ \centering \arraybackslash}P{4cm}|m{12cm}|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|>{ \centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}|}{ \color{white} Aim \cellcolor{black}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{12cm}|}{ \color{white} Explanation \cellcolor{black}} \\
            \hline
            Aim 1
            & 
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
            
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\
            \hline
            Aim 2
            &
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
            
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Overview of Aims}
        \label{table:1}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

thanks!

Comment: Please make your code compilable. See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Which documentclass do you use and how is the `P` type column defined?

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, I have made it compilable, please see the update code. I have also included the definition for P. This should now work by copying and pasting and then compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to adding `>{\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}}`, I have also used the `tabularx` package in order to make sure your table fits in the margins.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % instead of color and colortbl
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table*}[ht]
            \centering
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|>{\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}}X|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ \color{white} Aim \cellcolor{black}}
                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \color{white} Explanation \cellcolor{black}} \\
                \hline
                Aim 1
                & 
  
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
    
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\
                \hline
                Explanation
                &

    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
        
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \\
                \hline
            \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Overview of Aims}
            \label{table:1}
        \end{table*}
        
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @leandriis! Is there a way to get the first column text centered like the title?

Comment: Use a `c` type column instead of an `l` type column as in: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|>{\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}}X|}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, its almost there! Is there a setting to vertically center it too? The c column solves the horizontal center

Comment: At least in the code in my answer, the contents of the first column already are vertically centered. Do you get a different output? If so, please show a screenshot of what you get. Did you use the exact same code as in my answer or did you incorporate it into your actual document? If the latter is the case, please make sure, you also add `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` to the preamble of your actual document, just as I did in my answer.

Comment: Ah nvm! I had to hit compile 2 times and it seems to have sorted it. Thanks a lot for your help, I was lost in the complexity of Latex.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I was able to help.